# How should I toggle JQuery ajax on or off based on .NET Auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

**Firstly** is there a way to turn JQuery Ajax On or Off globally? I'm looking for something similar to this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/ - but for $.ajax.

**Secondly** what is the best way to set an On/Off flag based on whether a user is logged in?

*I am using ASP.NET MVC3.*

Comment: Just for interest, do you want to do this because of awkward logon screen with ajax requests?

Comment: @archil I've built an app that works when someone is logged in, some DB reads/writes are facilitated via ajax method calls. However for people who are not logged in I would still like the app to work, but make use of localstorage only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it sorted - extend the $.ajax method.

```
(function($)
{
    // store original reference to the method
    var oldAjax = $.ajax;
    $.ajax = function(prop, value) {
        // execute new behaviour
        if ($.ajax.Off) return false;
        // execute original behaviour
        return oldAjax.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then I simply set `$.ajax.Off` to `true` to disable ajax calls.

As for the second part I'll just set a hidden input or something...